# Android: Changing activity start my app depending on whether the user is logged in or not?

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, android-launcher

I have to make a start like spotify, if the user is not logged'll show a screen and if logged show another screen, anyone can help ?, thanks.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Have you done any other research? Show us some code?

Answer (score 6):

Try this code, It may helpful for you.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
boolean isUserLoggedIn = true;
// User Session Manager Class
UserSessionManager session;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    isUserLoggedIn = session.isUserLoggedIn();
    if(isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        SplashActivity.this.finish();
    }
    else
    {
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e) { }
            finally
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
    }
}}
```

UserSessionManager Class :-

```
public class UserSessionManager
{
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
Context _context;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences pref;

public UserSessionManager(Context paramContext)
{
    this._context = paramContext;
    this.pref = this._context.getSharedPreferences("AndroidPref", this.PRIVATE_MODE);
    this.editor = this.pref.edit();
}

public void createUserLoginSession(String paramString1, String paramString2)
{
    this.editor.putBoolean("IsUserLoggedIn", true);
    this.editor.putString("name", paramString1);
    this.editor.putString("email", paramString2);
    this.editor.commit();
}

public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails()
{
    HashMap<String, String> localHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    localHashMap.put("name", this.pref.getString("name", null));
    localHashMap.put("email", this.pref.getString("email", null));
    return localHashMap;
}

public boolean isUserLoggedIn()
{
    return this.pref.getBoolean("IsUserLoggedIn", false);
}

public void logoutUser()
{

}}
```

You can set login detail using createUserLoginSession method.

If You don't want to use splash waiting.
simply remove setContentView method and Thread in SplashActivity class.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a "splash" activity that evaluates some persisted state (like an oauth token) and depending on that state, either start your login activity or go ahead into your root logged-in activity.

If this check is fast and you do everything inside of onCreate(), you won't even see this splash activity.  If the check takes a bit, you can show a splash view with a logo or whatever until it's done.

Don't forget to finish() the splash activity once you leave it (or start the new one with the clear task flags).  Otherwise, when your user presses back, they will hit the splash activity instead of closing out of your application as expected.